# Shape [-1, 1] has negative dimensions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-serving

I'm working on a single class classification problem on tensorflow. The training has finished and I saved my model. When I try to call for prediction using google cloud, I get this error:

```
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: Error during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details=\"Shape [-1,1] has negative dimensions\n\t [[
Node: outputs = Placeholder[_output_shapes=[[-1,1]], dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1], _device=\"/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0\"]()]]\")"
}
```

I defined my prediction signature for outputs as the build_tensor_info of the output variable I defined as following:

```
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes], name = 'outputs')
```

Training and testing work fine on my laptop and on google cloud. It's only when I call for predictions that I get this error. I use this code to call for predictions:

```
gcloud ml-engine predict --model ${MODEL_NAME} --json-instances request.json
```

I believe this is a simple issue that I'm missing about how shape works in python/tensorflow.

Has anyone else had this issue before?

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow do you use? You may consult the list of supported versions and their supported packages on the [Cloud ML Runtime Version List](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/runtime-version-list). 
You may [specify custom versions of TensorFlow for training](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/versioning#custom-tf-versions).

Comment: @George Thanks for your comment. I have no problem training and creating my model. It's only when I call gcloud ml-engine predict --model ${MODEL_NAME} --json-instances request.json that I'm getting this error.

Comment: You do not mention cloud storage and creating a bucket, one of the usual steps prior to actual call for predictions. It's advisable to read the ["Getting Started"](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/getting-started-training-prediction) online document and make sure you have followed all needed steps.

Comment: My model is already in my bucket on gCloud @George. Otherwise, the error wouldn't complain about the properties of my output variable.